# How to do multiple requests on a map and catch all errors with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, request, try-catch

I have an app in which I'm getting some posts from the user and I'm then pushing each of them into a GitHub repo.
However, I would like to catch all the errors that might come from this map.
How could I achieve that? Currently my useState is, of course, replacing the previous state there and I'm unsure on how to proceed.
Here's the code:

```js
const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([])

const triggerPostsBackup = (postsData) => {
  posts.map(async (post) => {
    try {
     await THE_REQUEST
    } catch (error) {
      const errorString = `${post.title} failed to upload!`
      setErrors(errors.concat(errorString))
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

I've also tried to set an inner variable to keep all the errors and, at the end of the map, use a `useState` to create the state for my errors but I completely failed there

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.allSettled` to capture the result of each request. Then, after all requests are complete, you can reduce over them, pushing rejected promises into an error array. Then finally, call setErrors.

```js
const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([]);

const triggerPostsBackup = async (postsData) => {
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(
    posts.map(async (post) => {
      await THE_REQUEST;
    })
  );

  const errors = results.reduce<string[]>((acc, next, index) => {
    if (next.status === 'rejected') {
      acc.push(`${posts[index].title} failed to upload!`);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  setErrors(errors);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin. I wasn't aware of `Promise.allSettled()`.
I've tried to use `Promise.all()` but it didn't work.
I ended up reaching a solution by myself which seems to work but will give yours a go as well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my issue.
I was able to solve it with a `callback` ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) and it looks like this:

```js
const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string[]>([])

const triggerPostsBackup = (postsData) => {
  posts.map(async (post) => {
    try {
     await THE_REQUEST
    } catch (error) {
      const errorString = `${post.title} failed to upload!`
      setErrors((previousState) => [...previousState, errorString])
    }
  }
}
```